# How can I remove all non alpha numeric characters and leading zeros

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, pcre

I want to remove everything from a string using regular expression except alpha and numeric characters and I need any leading zero removed.

The below works but does not remove leading zeros

```
$string = '00000000A1234567890-=qwesss     €#¢∞§¶¶•ªº–  ≠≠rtyuuiop[]\';lkjhgfdsazxcvbnm,./';

$pattern = '/([^\da-z]/i)';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

How can i alter the pattern to remove leading Zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will work:

```
<?php
$string = '00000000A1234567890-=qwesss     €#¢∞§¶¶•ªº–  ≠≠rtyuuiop[]\';lkjhgfdsazxcvb00000nm,./';

$pattern = '#^(0*)|([^\da-z])#i';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

**EDIT**

This pattern can also be simplified to:

```
$pattern = '#^0+|\W#';
```

Comment: @user3172174 I've also added alternative pattern that also should work

Comment: I am struggling to use this function in mysql. I have made another post her http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839022/using-mysql-egex-replace-with-a-regular-expression if you have any suggestions. Your code works really well in PHP thanks

Answer (score 4):

This should work to satisfy both requirements:

```
$string = '00000000A1234567890-=qwesss     €#¢∞§¶¶•ªº–  ≠≠rtyuuiop[]\';lkjhgfdsazxcvbnm,./';
$pattern = '/^0+|[^\dA-Za-z]+/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
//=> 1234567890qwesssrtyuuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm
```

Comment: Not really a problem, but you don't need the i modifier since the character class already includes it. :)

Comment: Yes thanks @AmalMurali.. I just copy pasted OP's regex and it was a left over.

Comment: +1 for correct answer, as the currently accepted answer will not strip underscore `_` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$string = '00000000A1234567890-=qwesss     €#¢∞§¶¶•ªº–       ≠≠rtyuuiop[]\';lkjhgfdsazxcvbnm,./';

$pattern = '/([\W])/i';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

And if you also want delete zeros pattern is:

```
$pattern = '/([\W0])/i';
```

Comment: OP want to remove the lead zeros