# using mysql regex_replace with a regular expression

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am using regex_replace function found here
http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/

This function works well in php but seem's not to like hash's. I am using this pattern

```
#^(0*)|([^\da-z])#i
```

in a regular expression found here
[How can I remove all non alpha numeric characters and leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801900/how-can-i-remove-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-and-leading-zeros)

How can i make this work in mysql either my changing the mysql function or adjusting the expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT regex_replace('^0+|[^0-9a-zA-Z]','',sometextfield)
```

**Explanation**

- The `regex_replace` function you are trying to use is for MySQL and does not use delimiters like PHP, so we can remove the `#`
- We can also remove the parentheses which serve no purpose
- The `0*` should be changed to `0+`, otherwise we are replacing an empty string

**What does the regex do?**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `0+` matches one or more zeroes
- OR `|`
- `[^0-9a-zA-Z]` match a character that is neither a digit or a letter

Comment: FYI: added explanation to what the regex does.

Comment: If I do this select  
regex_replace('^0*|[^\da-z]','','0001234576890-!@£$%^&&**(*)_QWERTYUIOIOP{:L008817171771KJHGFDS?"}{FFDSSS') as relpace; it returns blank

Comment: This worked. Thanks ^0+|\W . Your tips made me understand. I have accepted your answer

Comment: On further tests the ^0+ removes all zeros if their are leading zeros this only happens in mysql this is my current code ^0+|[^0-9a-zA-Z] any tips

Comment: When I say ^0+ removes all zeros I mean it removes all zeros from any position in the string if a leading zero exists. This is not happening in php

Comment: `^0+` just removes leading zeroes. That's not what you want? That's an exact translation of the regex in the spec. If you want a conditional replacement, it will not be possible with `regex_replace` as MySQL `REGEXP` does not support lookbehind and other features to do this.

Comment: The code works in pHP, I want to remove all non alpha numeric characters and leading zeros. If i run it in mysql it works BUT if any string contains a leading zero it removes all zeros (anywhere) this is only an issue if their are leading zeros.

Comment: Ah, okay then, we're talking about the same thing—removing leading zeroes—wasn't sure I understood your last comment. I had a look at `regex_replace`. It's quite crude, it won't work like the regex engine in PHP (PCRE) which is hundreds of lines of code. After making one replacement, it will try making a replacement on the next substring, and it does not honor the `^`  beginning of string marker (it applies it to the beginning of the next substring). The workarnd would be to do it in two passes: one without the `^0+|` using the function. And one using MySQL string functions for the leading 0s.

Comment: Thank you so MUCH. I did this and it worked. TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM regex_replace('[^0-9a-zA-Z]','','000656000---0515ga000hhagag%@£$%^&*--LLKH')). Should have done that hours ago!!